# Automatic and manual slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to make a slideshow that has to work both automatic and manual.

For the manual part I have two buttons: next and previous that allows me to see the photos without having to wait a certain period of time between images.

When I don't click on the buttons, the slideshow goes automatic and the images change after six seconds (for example).

My problem is that, after I click on the previous/ next button, the images start to appear faster or they appear more than one on the screen.

Here is the code I am working with:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");

  if (n===undefined){n= ++slideIndex;}
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1;}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}

  $(slides[slideIndex-1]).fadeIn(2000);
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  $(slides[slideIndex-1]).delay(3000);
  $(slides[slideIndex-1]).fadeOut(1000);

  setTimeout(showSlides, 6000);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lab5.css" media="screen" title="no title">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="titlu">Goodies</h1>
  <div align="center">
    <button class="button" onclick="plusSlides(-1)" >Previous</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="plusSlides(1)" >Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h4 class="num" > 1 / 5 </h4>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150?text=1">
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h4 class="num"> 2 / 5 </h4>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150?text=2">
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h4 class="num"> 3 / 5 </h4>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150?text=3">
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h4 class="num"> 4 / 5 </h4>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150?text=4">
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h4 class="num"> 5 / 5 </h4>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150?text=5">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way I can make the slideshow return to its "speed" of showing the images every six seconds after I click on previous/next?

Also, how can I prevent it from showing more than one image at a time?

Comment: Just a little remark: you can use `if (!n) {...}` instead of `if (n===undefined) {...}`. It's more short and readable.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide, I wouldn't recommend that - especially when working  with numbers or any kind of type that might have a value that is falsy (e.g., 0, ''), as `!0 === true`.

Comment: @JanS, sure, if someone wants to use `if (!n) {...}` construction, he needs to know about **coercion** and the behavior of primitives

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What's happening is that you are causing multiple timers to be started, which causes your callback function to run more often than it should.**

You need to make sure that you capture the integer that is returned from your timer:

```
var timer = null; // Do this in a scope that is accessible to all your relevant functions
```

...then:

```
timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 6000);
```

So that you can cancel the timer where appropriate:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

You will want to clear your timer upon the clicking of the button, which will stop the automatic one from running and then you can start a new one, leaving you with only one running timer.

Comment: Thanks !  :) I also had to add this:

 ` for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  } `  
before the displaying of the picture!

Answer (score 10):

Here's working code for an auto and manual slideshow with the timer as suggested by Scott.
It works with the html and css from this how to which the questioner based his code on.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

```
var slideIndex = 1;
var timer = null;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex}
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jon Whatson and @Scott_Marcus.  This is perfect!  :)
The only thing I would note is that the "slides" and "dots" variables should be declared outside the scope of the function to avoid issues if anything other than ClassNames are being targeted (ul, li, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
<body>

<h2 class="w3-center">Manual Slideshow</h2>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">

  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

**SCRIPT CODES**
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>


**//CSS CODES**
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  height:500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  with:800px;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
    background-color:gold;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 7 7px 7px 7;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color:white;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color:lime;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color:lime;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #ff0101;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.2s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 6.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
```

Comment: THIS CODE MIGHT BE HELP FULL JUS T TRY

Comment: How exactly is this code helpful to the question? What differs from the OP's code? Can you explain?

Comment: The question is about  image appears on screen  more than one and when click prev or next button it slide faster so i just modify the codes using css and javascript