# Automatic and manual slideshow with a play and stop button

Tags: javascript, html, image, gallery, slideshow

Hello I was looking to Automatic and Manual slideshow topic here in stackoverflow. ([Automatic and manual slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638969/automatic-and-manual-slideshow/45571384#45571384)) And  I found a great answer for it which  modifies the scrip from w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow). however, I was wondering if there is a way add to the scrip  below a way to stop the slideshow and then let it back in automatic play. I think this would be useful if you want to see an image a bit longer and then after a while let it back again to playing mode.

```
var slideIndex = 1;
var timer = null;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex}
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);
}
```

the whole html would look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
var timer = null;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex}
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 1000);
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this code can be copy paste it in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow and it will function without the stop and play button or similar

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as show what you've tried so far.

Comment: It seems that you could alternately [`clearTimeout(timer)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) and `showSlides(slideIndex)` depending, for example, on button clicks.

Comment: I have pasted the the entire html and it can be replaced by the code set on https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow. Again I am having troubles in being able to stop and replay de automatic play. I do not necessarily  need a button it can be anything that stops and replays